# The reason for final in the Linked List Implementation

Tags: java

In the linked list implementation `final` is used in a lot of places. For example

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

Why is `final` needed in the above implementation? A a new reference is created (`l`) so that `last` can be modified and overridden.

Comment: If you get into the habit of marking everything that can be final as final, then whenever you see something that is *not* marked final, you'll know it is being assigned to, and won't accidentally miss it. So it's good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` local variables are not really needed here. It just gives an indication to the future developers, that the variable would not be modified further in the method. Of course, in the above method, we would not want the value of references `l` and `newNode` to change at any point in the method. With `final` there, compiler would give you error, *if you(or one of your team mate) accidentally do one such change*.

Moreover, this might also make compiler to do some *minor optimization* on it's own part, like making a primitive type referring to a compile time constant `final`, will make compiler to inline those variables wherever they are used inside the method. Note that `final` modifier *doesn't* make it to the bytecode, so the *runtime performance* is absolutely unaffected. As said above, it's just there for the purpose of showing the intention of developer, and nothing more than that.

Comment: To clarify the above post: `final` is anyways not related to functionality per se so there would never be situations wherein you would *absolutely* need to use `final` to implement something. Also for fields `final` basically means " a given reference *would* and *should* never be re-assigned".

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Of course, that is what I'm trying to convey here.

Comment: Well, in your original post you mentioned "final local variables are not really needed here, as far as functionality is concerned" which might mean there are some cases wherein final affects the functionality. My comment was more of a clarification mentioning that's never the case.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Yeah, I removed that part. I knew you were referring to that line only. That was misleading really.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are storing a copy of the instance variable 'last' in our method in the variable 'l',
the 'l' will be pointing to the object which 'last' was pointing.  We need to make it sure that during the course of the method  we don't loose the pointer to that object.
Therefore it is final which says that it will only point to the object which 'last' was referring

Answer (score 0):

Once the identity of a final object reference is set, it can still change its state, but not its identity (that is, you can't re-point the object reference to some other object).

In the above snippet we do not want in any case to have the reference l point to some other object. Hence we have the final modifier. This reference is very important since we need to know the element to link the new element too. We cannot risk losing this reference and hence its marked as final.